# Utility of displacements potentials in geophysics

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, geophysics, elasticity

In the elasticity theory, you can derive a wave equation from the fundamental equation of motion for an elastic linear homogeneous isotropic medium:

$\rho \partial^2_t \overline{u} = \mu \nabla^2 \overline{u} + (\mu+\lambda) \nabla(\nabla \cdot \overline{u})$

But in the seismology tradition, you introduce scalar and vector potentials for the P and S components of the displacements, derive wave equations for them and use them.

Now, in electrodynamics you can derive from Maxwell's equations the wave equations for Fields and for Potentials; but there you use the potentials because they compose a quadrivector. In geophysics what's the convenience of it?

Comment: I edited your question for grammar and spelling a bit, hope you don't mind.  Feel free to roll back if you disagree with the changes, but please leave the tags I added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe potentials in Maxwell's equations were introduced originally to make solving equations simpler -- it wasn't until a bit later that the Lorentz symmetry was noticed. Similar potentials are introduced in 2D hydrodynamics as well, see e.g. [stream function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function).  So I would say that the reason for introducing these potentials originally was always to simplify the algebra.

Of course, whenever one has some nice trick like this, there's a deeper reason.  Here the "deeper reason" for introducing various potentials has to do with the [Helmholtz decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) (even deeper, coming from the [Hodge decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_decomposition#Hodge_decomposition)), which guarantees that vector fields can be written as a sum of a curl-free vector field and a divergence-free vector field.  This decomposition "plays nicely" with wave equations in the sense that there are natural wave modes, transverse (divergence-free) and longitudinal (curl-free) which propagate independently.  See the discussion of [transverse and longitudinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Longitudinal_and_transverse_fields), i.e. the application of the Helmholtz decomposition to a Fourier transform of a vector field, which obviously is highly applicable to the P (longitudinal) and S (transverse) waves in seismology.

Intuitively, the idea of the Helmholtz decomposition is a bit like breaking a vector into independent components, and then calculating what happens to each separately, except now one is working with vector fields.

Answer (score 1):

Also, adding to what j.c. states:

If you have a complicated constitutive relation between the electric field and the electric displacement field, e.g. nonlinear and in terms of a convolution (no instantanious reaction of the medium), it might be very complicated to find a representation in terms of potentials obaying a wave equation using a non-perturbative ansatz.